# mysql update script

Tags: php

Anyone who can point a php novice in the right direction? It won't update the database and I can't figure it out. I get the article that I want to change and put it a form, and use the "update1.php" file to update the database.

Getting the article:

```
<?php
include ('../db_connect.php');

$getid = $_GET['artikkelID'];

$query = mysql_query('SELECT tittel, ingress, publ, tekst, forfatter, bildetekst, photo FROM hovedartikler WHERE artikkelID = "' . $getid . '"');
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$titteldb = $rows['tittel'];
$ingressdb = $rows['ingress'];
$tekstdb = $rows['tekst'];
$forfatterdb = $rows['forfatter'];
$bildetekstdb = $rows['bildetekst'];
$photodb = $rows['photo'];

echo '<form action="update1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<span>
ArtikkelID 
<input type="text" name="artikkelID" readonly="readonly" size="3" value="' . $getid . '">
</span>

<span style="margin-left: 20px;">
Artikkelens Tittel ( maks 100 tegn)
<input type="text" name="tittel" cols="80" size="50" value="' . $titteldb . '" /><br />
</span>
<br />

Ingress (maks 255 tegn)<br />
<textarea name="ingress" rows="4" cols="60" />' . $ingressdb . '</textarea><br />

Artikkelens tekst (ingen begrensning på antall tegn)<br />
<textarea id="textarea1" name="tekst" size="100%">' . $tekstdb . '</textarea>
<script language="javascript1.2">
generate_wysiwyg("textarea1");
</script>


Skriv inn artikkelens forfatter (maks 50 tegn)<br />
<input type="text" name="forfatter" size="80" cols="80" value="' . $forfatterdb . '" /><br />

Skriv inn tekst til artikkel-bilde<br />
<textarea name="bildetekst" rows="3" cols="60">' . $bildetekstdb . '</textarea><br />

Last opp bilde til bruk i artikkelen<br />
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
<input type="file" name="file" size="80" value="' .   $photodb . '" /><br />

<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Oppdater" />
</form>';   

?>
```

And the update-script:

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['artikkelID'];
$tittel = $_POST['tittel'];
$ingress = $_POST['ingress'];
$tekst = $_POST['tekst'];
$forfatter = $_POST['forfatter'];
$bildetekst = $_POST['bildetekst'];
$pic = $_FILES['file']['name'];



include '../db_connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['Oppdater']))

$mysql_query=("UPDATE hovedartikler SET 
tittel='" . $_POST['tittel'] . "', ingress='" . $_POST['ingress'] . "', tekst='" . $_POST['tekst'] . "', forfatter='" . $_POST['forfatter'] . "', bildetekst='" . $_POST['bildetekst'] . "', file='" . $_FILES['pic'] . "' WHERE artikkelID='$id'")
or die (mysql_error());

mysql_query($query);
echo "Artikkelen er oppdatert!<br/><br/>
Du vil n&aring; automatisk bli dirigert til Admin-forsiden.";

print_r($ingress);

mysql_close();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("window.location.href='http://mss-seil.no/admin/adminIndex.php'", 3000);
</script>
```

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For a start **stop** using `mysql_*` functions and start using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements with bound values or you will face [SQL injection attacks](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Secondly, for now change `mysql_query($query)` to `mysql_query($mysql_query)` and remove the brackets from around the actual query and the die statement when setting the variable. You are trying to run the query held in `$query` but the UPDATE query is actually held in `$mysql_query`

It should look more like this:

```
$mysql_query = "UPDATE hovedartikler SET 
tittel='" . $_POST['tittel'] . "', ingress='" . $_POST['ingress'] . "', tekst='" . $_POST['tekst'] . "', forfatter='" . $_POST['forfatter'] . "', bildetekst='" . $_POST['bildetekst'] . "', file='" . $_FILES['pic'] . "' WHERE artikkelID='$id'";

mysql_query($mysql_query);
```

Comment: Thanks. I promise to look at the SQL injection attacks problem!

Comment: I did your changes, but it still don't works. I print the $ingress in the script, and it shows the alterations I do in the form. So I guess it's how the UPDATE is laid out that is the problem. Would you write it in a very different way?

Answer (score 1):

```
$mysql_query=("UPDATE hovedartikler SET tittel='" . $_POST['tittel'] . "', ingress='" . $_POST['ingress'] . "', tekst='" . $_POST['tekst'] . "', forfatter='" . $_POST['forfatter'] . "', bildetekst='" . $_POST['bildetekst'] . "', file='" . $_FILES['pic'] . "' WHERE artikkelID='$id'") or die (mysql_error());
```

Note it's "$mysql_query" not "$query".

```
mysql_query($mysql_query);
```

Just a few side notes too:

- the mysql_* functions should not really be used now. Take a look at [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).
- You are not sanitizing your input before inserting it into the database. This is **not** a good idea - you're leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks. You should escape strings and cast integers as integers. If you follow the first suggestion and use PDO or mysqli, look into using prepared statements.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Please look for SQL-Injections and escape your values from $_POST, please :) - And the Javascript-redirect can be replaced with a server-sided PHP-redirect with "header", I guess.

```
$mysql_query=("UPDATE hovedartikler SET 
tittel='" . $_POST['tittel'] . "', ingress='" . $_POST['ingress'] . "', tekst='" . $_POST['tekst'] . "', forfatter='" . $_POST['forfatter'] . "', bildetekst='" . $_POST['bildetekst'] . "', file='" . $_FILES['pic'] . "' WHERE artikkelID='$id'")
or die (mysql_error());

mysql_query($query);
```

You've got a variable "$mysql_query" with the Update-Statement. But you send a variable "$query" to the mysql_query function. Shouldn't you send the $mysql_query variable to the mysql_query function? Maybe better variable names could be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is the cause but you are using different quotes in the two files.

In the getting:

```
"' . $getid . '"'
```

And in the setting

```
WHERE artikkelID='$id'"
```

What datatype is artikkelID?

If it is an int, the first will work as double quote is not a string quote but a "grouping" quote which can be used to have columns with reserved words names

The last will not work as single quote IS a string quote, and you cannot use string for an int column.

For example

I could query an int column like this

```
WHERE id > "20"
```

but not like this

```
WHERE id > '20'
```

Whereas for a string column

```
WHERE name = "Hello World"
```

Would try to match the name column with the Hello World column, not the Hello World string